# How to filter data coming from an API and store in an array by year and month?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am getting bank transaction data from API, I want to store the transaction by Year and Month, and display in chart.
below is the API, I am getting,Here I want to display the balance by month in the chart, so how to save data in array or other data structure by year and month.

```
[
{
    "id": "d470154c-4cbe-4af3-bc60-d710981a69d6",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "amount": 70.51,
    "category": "amusement",
    "balance": 894.22,
    "date": "2019-02-18T07:09:00.093",
    "direction": "DEBIT",
    "reference": "DUBLIN ZOO"
},
{
    "id": "ba54812f-e9a4-40bc-a244-b679470684e4",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "amount": 50.37,
    "category": "car fuel",
    "balance": 1846.72,
    "date": "2018-12-26T15:15:00.176",
    "direction": "DEBIT",
    "reference": "SHUTTINGTON"
},
{
    "id": "e9ac1822-f550-4cf4-8f4a-b53e7c540463",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "amount": 69.06,
    "category": "shopping",
    "balance": 1637.59,
    "date": "2018-07-22T13:42:00.440",
    "direction": "DEBIT",
    "reference": "DISNEY STORE"
},
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how can we help you without even seeing the json?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I have added the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all transactions. After that you need to make some control which will present your transaction and some filter function that will take all transactions and filter it with month or year. So if your all transaction stored in some `transactions` variable, your filter function need to filter transactions variable and then store the result in other `presentableTransactions` variable. And then you need to present `presentableTransactions`.